# How to Cut DIV Corner with Radius SVG or CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to cut bottom right corner of DIV with border-radius, such as both images bellow:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following codes are almost similar to what you want. Of course, I set the background shape to white by default, you should set it according to the parent background.

I hope it is useful for you

```css
.card {
        width: 340px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: aqua;
        border-radius: 32px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .card::before {
        content: "";
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        right: -4px;
        bottom: 86px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 64px;
        box-shadow: 0 20px 0 0 #ffffff;
      }

      .card::after {
        content: "";
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        right: 86px;
        bottom: -4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 64px;
        box-shadow: 20px 0 0 0 #ffffff;
      }

      .card .shape {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        right: 8px;
        bottom: 8px;
        z-index: 99;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .card .shape::after {
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 80px solid transparent;
        border-right: 80px solid #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 80px solid #ffffff;
        border-left: 80px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        right: -32px;
        bottom: -32px;
      }

      .zoom {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .card img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img
    src="https://demo.zebardast.dev/codepen/photography.png"
    alt="image"
  />
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is not like my image :(

Comment: you're welcome.
Yes, it's true, if you change a little css code, it will probably look like the picture